# Anyone know why matlab would show many significant digits for no reason?

Tags: matlab, floating-point-precision

Example command and output:

```
>> 15.12

ans =

  15.119999999999999"
```

I'm trying to show only two significant digits (I'm putting values into a uitable) so this is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely cause is that you have set `format long`.

Try typing `format` or `format short` at Matlab prompt.

Example:

```
>> format long
>> 15.12
ans 
  15.119999999999999   
>> format
>> 15.12
ans =
   15.1200
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to show two digits use

```
>> format bank
>> 15.2

ans =

         15.20
```

See the [Matlab Doc](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/format.html) for further details.